# Why is ftp output in a different order

Tags: cmd, ftp

I am running an FTP script using Windows ftp.exe. The script does not do `ls -al` until after all of the `put` commands. However, the directory listing appears much earlier in the output. Why is that? Can I do anything to cause the output to be in the same order as the script?

```
open ftpserver.example.com
user acme
********
pwd
cd outbound/work
pwd
binary
put "1568_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "1568_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9269_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9269_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9270_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9270_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9272_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9272_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9273_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9273_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
ls -al
bye
```

===================================

```
C:> ftp -i -n -s:"C:\Users\acme\AppData\Local\Temp\acme_ftp_script_2018-06-19T07-01-17.tmp"
open ftpserver.example.com
user acme

pwd
257 "/home/ftp/acme" is current directory.
cd outbound/work
pwd
257 "/home/ftp/acme/outbound/work" is current directory.
total 1368
drwxr-xr-x   2 acme  ftpgroup      13824 Jun 19 07:10 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 acme  ftpgroup        512 May 09 12:36 ..
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup      12529 Jun 19 07:10 1568_ACME_20180619065804.csv
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup          0 Jun 19 07:10 1568_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup     572681 Jun 19 07:10 9269_ACME_20180619065804.csv
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup          0 Jun 19 07:10 9269_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup      21920 Jun 19 07:10 9270_ACME_20180619065804.csv
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup          0 Jun 19 07:10 9270_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup      34920 Jun 19 07:10 9272_ACME_20180619065804.csv
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup          0 Jun 19 07:10 9272_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup      26973 Jun 19 07:10 9273_ACME_20180619065804.csv
-rw-r-----   1 acme  ftpgroup          0 Jun 19 07:10 9273_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new
binary
put "1568_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "1568_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9269_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9269_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9270_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9270_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9272_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9272_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
put "9273_ACME_20180619065804.csv"
put "9273_ACME_20180619065804.csv.ctl.new"
ls -al
bye
```